# Connection Disappeared in Connection Pool

Tags: c#, connection-pooling, ado

I'm reading connection pool from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
I face with this sentence:

> If a connection exists to a server that has disappeared, this
>   connection can be drawn from the pool even if the connection pooler
>   has not detected the severed connection and marked it as invalid. This
>   is the case because the overhead of checking that the connection is
>   still valid would eliminate the benefits of having a pooler by causing
>   another round trip to the server to occur. When this occurs, the first
>   attempt to use the connection will detect that the connection has been
>   severed, and an exception is thrown.

Can everybody explain disappeared connection?And why a connection will be disappeared ?

Comment: It says *a server that has disappeared*, not a connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the connection which disappears. A pooled connection is an established network connection. Now until data is sent over the connection, a problem with the connectivity to the server (e.g. network issue) may not be detected.

Therefore, the following can happen:

- Connections are open to a SQL Server, and get added to the pool
- The network link gets broken (in a way which is not immediately detected, such as a router problem; an unplugged cable on the client would likely be detected right away)
- Shortly after an application draws a pooled connection from the pool
- The connection is returned as if the server was reachable, because no check is done to verify this (which is what the quoted information is about)
- On first use an exception will be thrown